# Wireless issue in lenovo g40-30

Tags: networking, lenovo

i see in the forum differents steps to repair the issue i got in my computer, i got computer Lenovo g40-30, the issue is; the wireless or wifi connect for a few minutes and after some time, the connection is drop, and i need to reboot the ocmputer and have internet again or just connect connect by wire in LAN, when i restar the computer i see this:
~$ sudo rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

To be honest, i dont have much time using Ubuntu but i got some idea, can you help me to know what should i do in the issue? And still the change to dont restar my computer.

64bit 
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

thank you for your time, have a great day.

Comment: if i put command:

sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all

Works during few minutes, but not back again, i check in Bios if the wireless is disable, but is enable.
What should i do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To specify i got this Lenovo G40-30 with XUbuntu 64bits.

i got good news!! i resolve this with more help, for example, first i have the help for other guy who work with laptops and he told me verify first what kind os PCI wireless the unit have installed in this computer, and i see i have INTEL not REALTEK the model is 
WirelessLan_Non_Intel, Cbt RTL8723BE
1x1BN+BT4.0 PCIE M.2 WLAN
So i found some information with put in the terminal "uname -r" i have "3.13.0-74-generic" and i didi the steps in the webpage http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261702

```
sudo modpobe -r rtl8723be
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" sudo tee -a /etc/moprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo modprobe rtl823be

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

After i reboot the unit and put:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

And last thing! to keep changes put:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Restart your computer

And for now is working, i dont have cut signal and still online more than the time i was working.
Im not expertice with Linux, but this help a lot, and i would like continue working with Linux.

Comment: You did too many things. The first part from github is not needed, or the last part with ppa. I am afraid that now the driver is blacklisted and it will not be built by dkms.